# Mercurial ssh send revision at some tag name

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I want mercurial server to ssh-send some revision to some production server (customer's side) on specific tag name set by any user. Something very similar to Continuous Integration platform that pushes updates to agents at certain criterion.

Comment: Right, and what's the problem?

Comment: There is no problem, I want to know on how to do it.

Comment: @djc I don't want the whole repository to be pushed to the customer, I just want the tagged branch/revision to be sent to the customer, that each tag with some name will be pushed to some customer according to the name of the tag .. is that possible in Mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't centrally do anything if someone sets a tag. Mercurial is decentralized, so unless all your developers install a hook for this on their machines, you can't initiate anything from their local actions.

On the other hand, what you could is install a hook on a server they push to, that pushes a revision to some other client or server iff the .hgtags file has changed in the latest revision (and you could inspect exactly how it has changed from the hook code).

Comment: Nice answer djc, may be my question wasn't very clear, yes, I wanted the plugin to be on the server. And I didn't know that there is and .hgtags in mercurial, I need to dig deeper then I might have more questions, plus one for now :)